# Please tag your Bible verses with the version of the Bible you are quoting from

Tags: discussion, bible-quotes, bible

Every time I see a Bible verse with a few words that are slightly different or even out of the ordinary, the first thought that comes to mind is the **version** of the Bible the verse was quoted from; whether it was from *King James Version (KJV)*, *New King James Version (NKJV)*, *New International Version (NIV)*, etc.

For example, we have John 3:16:

King James Version:

> For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that
>   whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting
>   life. (KJV)

New King James Version:

> For God so loved the world that He gave His only begotten Son, that
>   whoever believes in Him should not perish but have everlasting life.
>   (NKJV)

New International Version:

> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that
>   whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life. (NIV)

Only a few words change such as "only Son" vs "only begotten Son" and "believeth" vs "believe".

This is a simple suggestion to make it is easier to know which version of the Bible they are quoting from right away without looking it up.

Regards,

Comment: I always do that, namely because I do not have a religious preference in bible versions. I just use whatever's convenient. :D

Comment: Or link to the verse in context, that should be sufficient too.

Comment: While copying a verse for SE purposes is almost certainly fair use, tagging like this will satisfy copyright holders, too.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to see a convenient way to pass either the reference or ref + text, and have it format the quote nicely with a link to popup from BibleGateway or somewhere that lets the viewer compare other versions if desired. This could be related to the "special blockquote for Bible text" if that idea is reconsidered.